# Evaluate $\int{\frac{e^{2x}} {\sqrt{1-e^x}}}\ dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate  $$\displaystyle\int{\frac{e^{2x}} {\sqrt{1-e^x}}}\ dx.$$

I tried to solve by using integration by parts, but I couldn't find a solution. What method should I use to integrate this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Can you tell us what you tried to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $e^{2x}$ or $e^2x$, as this drastically changes the difficulty of the integral

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Let $u=1-e^{x}$${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: by substitution ? But this integral its in the "integral by parts list", sorry bad english 

I tried u = (1-e^x)^-1/2

Comment: An alternative way to solve this using integration by parts is to notice that $\frac{e^{2x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{x}}}=\frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{x}}}e^{x}=\bigg(\frac{d}{dx}(2 \sqrt{1-e^{x}})\bigg)e^{x}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^x}}\underbrace{\Big(e^x \, dx\Big)}_{\text{HINT}}
$$

After that substitution (the one that is hinted at), use another substitution, namely a rationalizing substitution.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\frac{e^{2x}}{(1-e^x)^{1/2}}dx$$
$$I=\int\frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^{1/2}}e^xdx$$
Substitution: $u^2=1-e^x\Rightarrow -2udu=e^xdx$.
$$I=\int\frac{1-u^2}{(u^2)^{1/2}}(-2)udu$$
$$I=-2\int(1-u^2)du$$
$$I=2\int(u^2-1)du$$
$$I=2\int u^2du-2\int du$$
$$I=\frac{2u^4}{4}-2u$$
$$I=\frac{(1-e^x)^2}{2}-2\sqrt{1-e^x}+C$$